# Does $f<\infty$ a.s. imply that $f$ is integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f\colon\Omega\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ measurable. Does then $f<\infty$ a.s. imply that $f$ is integrable?

I think no, but cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: the integral can be unbounded and therefore not integrable

Comment: Presumably you mean this to be a space of finite measure so the characteristic function for the whole space fails to be non-integrable. But consider, say, $\frac 1x$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Mike How do you mean that, because $1/x$ is not defined for $x=0$.

Comment: There is no problem with @Mike's example. If you are using Lebesgue measure then, $\{0\}$ is a set with zero measure and therefore, is is irrelevant for the final result.

Answer (score 3):

Of course not. Take $\Omega=\mathbb R$, $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure, and $f(t)=1$.

Comment: Your functio is $<\infty$ surely not a.s., right? Of course then it is $<\infty$ a.s., too.

Comment: "a.s." (usually "a.e.") means "off a set of measure zero". The empty set is a set of measure zero.